# App stopped working - Fragment layout - Google Maps API v2

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I saw a lot of questions on stack overflow and no answer solved my problem, i tried to set a layout to the fragment and the app stops working again and again, i tried too many different templates for the fragment to be in relative layout and to be on it's own without relative layout and nothing happens but stops.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

when i replace the fragment with a textview or button the app works, thank you very much.

logCat

```
    07-06 05:44:00.002: ERROR/CellLocation(630): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:00.002: ERROR/CellLocation(13659): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:00.011: ERROR/CellLocation(15213): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:00.012: ERROR/CellLocation(13659): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:00.014: ERROR/CellLocation(15213): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:00.030: ERROR/FWKEXT(630): Enter GetCurrentOP
07-06 05:44:00.066: ERROR/CellLocation(13659): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:00.097: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Open fd: 69, file: /data/data/com.htc.weather.service/databases/weather.db-journal
07-06 05:44:00.098: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Close fd: 69
07-06 05:44:00.113: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Open fd: 69, file: /data/data/com.htc.weather.service/databases/weathersync.db-journal
07-06 05:44:00.116: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Close fd: 69
07-06 05:44:00.136: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Open fd: 69, file: /data/data/com.htc.weather.service/databases/weathersync.db-journal
07-06 05:44:00.136: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Close fd: 69
07-06 05:44:00.138: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Open fd: 68, file: /data/data/com.htc.weather.service/databases/weathersync.db-journal
07-06 05:44:00.138: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Close fd: 68
07-06 05:44:00.139: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Open fd: 68, file: /data/data/com.htc.weather.service/databases/weathersync.db-journal
07-06 05:44:00.159: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Close fd: 68
07-06 05:44:00.160: ERROR/FWKEXT(630): Enter GetCurrentOP
07-06 05:44:00.176: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Open fd: 69, file: /data/data/com.htc.weather.service/databases/weather.db-journal
07-06 05:44:00.176: ERROR/SQLiteLog(22227): (257) Close fd: 69
07-06 05:44:03.437: ERROR/CellLocation(630): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:03.439: ERROR/CellLocation(630): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:03.444: ERROR/CellLocation(13659): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:03.445: ERROR/CellLocation(15213): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:03.459: ERROR/CellLocation(15213): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:03.475: ERROR/CellLocation(13659): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:03.491: ERROR/CellLocation(13659): create GsmCellLocation
07-06 05:44:06.426: ERROR/BatteryService(630): Enter GetStatus success
07-06 05:44:06.427: ERROR/BatteryService(630): ioctl ok: 323
07-06 05:44:06.449: ERROR/BatteryService(630): Enter GetStatus success
07-06 05:44:06.450: ERROR/BatteryService(630): ioctl ok: 323
07-06 05:44:06.452: ERROR/BatteryService(630): Enter GetStatus success
07-06 05:44:06.453: ERROR/BatteryService(630): ioctl ok: 323
07-06 05:44:13.007: ERROR/Sensors(630): new acc setDelay handle(4),ns(100000000) err! go to hwmsen
07-06 05:44:13.484: ERROR/SQLiteLog(29957): (257) Open fd: 85, file: /data/data/com.avast.android.mobilesecurity/databases/avast.db-journal
07-06 05:44:13.485: ERROR/SQLiteLog(29957): (257) Close fd: 85
07-06 05:44:13.493: ERROR/SQLiteLog(29957): (257) Open fd: 85, file: /data/data/com.avast.android.mobilesecurity/databases/avast.db-journal
07-06 05:44:13.493: ERROR/SQLiteLog(29957): (257) Close fd: 85
07-06 05:44:13.862: ERROR/SQLiteLog(25946): (257) Open fd: 81, file: /data/data/com.facebook.orca/databases/prefs_db-journal
07-06 05:44:13.864: ERROR/SQLiteLog(25946): (257) Close fd: 81
07-06 05:44:13.866: ERROR/SQLiteLog(25946): (257) Open fd: 81, file: /data/data/com.facebook.orca/databases/prefs_db-journal
07-06 05:44:13.887: ERROR/SQLiteLog(25946): (257) Close fd: 81
07-06 05:44:16.425: ERROR/BatteryService(630): Enter GetStatus success
07-06 05:44:16.425: ERROR/BatteryService(630): ioctl ok: 323
07-06 05:44:16.426: ERROR/BatteryService(630): Enter GetStatus success
07-06 05:44:16.426: ERROR/BatteryService(630): ioctl ok: 323
07-06 05:44:16.427: ERROR/BatteryService(630): Enter GetStatus success
07-06 05:44:16.427: ERROR/BatteryService(630): ioctl ok: 323
07-06 05:44:18.388: ERROR/SQLiteLog(790): (257) Open fd: 121, file: /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db-journal
07-06 05:44:18.390: ERROR/SQLiteLog(790): (257) Close fd: 121
07-06 05:44:18.406: ERROR/SQLiteLog(790): (257) Open fd: 121, file: /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db-journal
07-06 05:44:18.406: ERROR/SQLiteLog(790): (257) Close fd: 121
07-06 05:44:23.628: ERROR/Sensors(630): new acc setDelay handle(4),ns(200000000) err! go to hwmsen
07-06 05:44:23.628: ERROR/Sensors(630): new acc setDelay handle(4),ns(100000000) err! go to hwmsen
07-06 05:44:23.645: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(630): Object tried to add another callback
07-06 05:44:23.645: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(630): java.lang.Exception: Called by
07-06 05:44:23.645: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(630):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardUpdateMonitor.registerCallback(KeyguardUpdateMonitor.java:1118)
07-06 05:44:23.645: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(630):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardSelectorView.onResume(KeyguardSelectorView.java:338)
07-06 05:44:23.645: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(630):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardHostView.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardHostView.java:1158)
07-06 05:44:23.645: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(630):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewManager.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardViewManager.java:406)
07-06 05:44:23.645: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(630):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.handleNotif
```

Here's my java code, the app stops when i hash the map code too, i believe it's something in the layout.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
      static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
      private GoogleMap map;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

        if (map!=null){
          Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
              .title("Hamburg"));
          Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(KIEL)
              .title("Kiel")
              .snippet("Kiel is cool")
              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                  .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        }

      } 
}
```

Comment: Is there google play service in your phone?

Comment: Yes i have google play service in my phone.

Comment: Filter the logs on your apps logs, and also post your fragment code.

Comment: How to filter log?! i filtered to get just errors, i can't understand it, it keeps running showing many different errors and warnings.

Comment: that error log makes no sense, where is the exception. Please clean and build your project

Comment: I just tried your code, it works fine for me.

Comment: It's working with all the tutorials i saw, I don't know why it's not working with me, did you set a layout for the fragment?! because the fragment in the GraphyicalLayout says "pick a preview layout for your fragment"

Answer (score 0):

Please post the log as it is not clear from your question.
One possible mistake can be => You are using [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) which extends [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). Try using [SupportMapFragment.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment)

Comment: I can't understand the logCat but i posted it.

Comment: @Neeraj Kumar it should work with MapFragment also both are the same unless you plan to support phones running on api 11 no need to use SupportMapFragment()